# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания вo фразе: "горшок он и в Африке горшок"?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в этой фразе?

> *горшок он и в Африке горшок*

Что должно стоять после горшок: запятая, тире или точка? Почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Аn em dash would be most appropriate, since we have a [thematic nominative, closely connected to the base sentence.](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-021.htm#i13147)

> При именительном темы, более тесно связанном с базовым предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, употребляется тире: *Смерть - она все успокаивает (М. Г.); Читатель - он знает, что важен не человек - важен дух человеческий (М. Г.); Марченко - тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.); Дорога в дождь - она не сладость, Дорога в дождь - она беда (Евт.).*
>
> If a thematic nominative is more closely connected to the base sentence which uses a personal or demonstrative pronoun as a reference word, an em dash is used to connect the sentences.

A [*thematic nominative*](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B), or topical nominative, is a rhetorical construct in Russian (and in English too) which uses a independent clause of a single expression in nominative to define a topic (or theme) of a compound sentence, and another indepenent clause to define the comment (or rheme).

In both English and Russian it's probably best illustrated by demotivators posted all over the Internet:

[image: demotivational image about cats]

A comma could be used too, since this expression is quite vernacular and a comma can be used instead of an em dash to imitate flow of speech. However, the expression *и в Африке* has already become an idiom.

Comment: Could you provide a translation of the quote you posted? Thanks. :)

Comment: "However, the expression и в Африке has already become an idiom." - does it matter? what are you pointing out at by saying this?

Comment: @bonomo: This construct is a colloquialism which could be styled as such in writing. However, it's not perceived as a colloquialism anymore.